# What is the range and sensitivity of the monsters' hearing?

Tags: a-quiet-place

In *A Quiet Place*, everyone has to stay silent or risk being hunted by the alien monsters. Has the range and sensitivity of their hearing ever been defined, or are there just lots of monsters distributed across the planet?